# CHECK ZOOKEEPER fails on install,start and test step

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ambari

I am getting error on CHECK ZOOKEEPER step during installation/deployment of my 5 node cluster using ambari while doing zookeeper smoke test.

when I proceed further, It shows many services has not started. Although when I start them manually, All services get up.
The problem occurs only once i.e., first time only during installation/deployment of cluster.

NOTE:- I am using zookeeper 3.4.14 version.

Here is my brief [stderr](https://hastebin.com/tececazaja.sql) and [stdout](https://hastebin.com/ucuvukuxom.pl).

and here is stderr summary

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 314, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
ExecutionFailed: Execution of '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/zkSmoke.sh /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client/bin/zkCli.sh ambari-qa /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client/conf 2181 False kinit no_keytab no_principal /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/zkSmoke.out' returned 3. zk_node1=ip-172-31-0-250.ca-central-1.compute.internal
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /zk_smoketest
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.delete(ZooKeeper.java:882)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:712)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:600)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:372)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:332)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:291)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Data associated with znode /zk_smoketests is not consistent on host ip-172-31-10-8.ca-central-1.compute.internal
Connecting to ip-172-31-0-250.ca-central-1.compute.internal:2181
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled
[zk: ip-172-31-0-250.ca-central-1.compute.internal:2181(CONNECTING) 0] delete /zk_smoketest
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /zk_smoketest
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.delete(ZooKeeper.java:882)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:712)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:600)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:372)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:332)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:291)
Zookeeper Smoke Test: Failed
```